# Determine if the set $C =\{ \frac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is open or closed in the euclidian metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidian metric$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - y_i)^2}$. I want to show with arguments or a proof that the set $C =\{ \frac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is open or closed.

I know that the graph of the function looks like:

[image]

Therefore I would argue that the set C is open in the euclidian metric.

I would really appreciate your answers!!!

Definition of **open**:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $U \subseteq X$. The set $U$ is called an open set if the following holds:

For every $U$ there exists some $\epsilon > 0 $ such that $B_\epsilon (x) \subseteq U$.

Definition of **closed**:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $F \subseteq X$. The set $F$ is called closed if $X/F$ is called open.

Comment: The set $C$ is not equal to the graph. It is merely those points on the graph whose $x$ values are integers. (PS: $C$ is neither closed nor open)

Comment: What's your definition of open? and the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb R$ is $|x-y|$ by the way.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan thx for your answer! OK I understand, but how do you come to the conclusion that C is neither closed nor open? Please write me an answer!

Comment: @azarel I updated both definitions!

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan The set $C$ is not equal to points on the graph, either. $C\subset \mathbb{R}$ while the graph is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Neal What would be a right graph for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ is not closed because $0$ is a limit point of $C$, but $O \notin C$.

$C$ is not open because, for any $x = 1/n \in C$, and any $\delta > 0$, there is a point $z\in \mathbb{R}\setminus C$ such that $x-\delta < z < x+\delta$

Answer (score 2):

The set $C =\{ \frac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is not open in $\mathbb R$. The reason is that for each $x\in C$ you cannot find a neighborhood of $x$ such that $N(x,r)\subset C$. For each neighborhood of $x=\frac{1}{n}$, it is possible to find $y$  such that $\frac{1}{n+1}<y<\frac{1}{n}$ which means that $y\notin C$.

**Some remarks:** The concept of open and closed is meaningful only with respect to a given topological space. If your space is $\mathbb R$ with Euclidean metric,  then the metric is $|x-y|$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$. It is also not pertinent to represent a set $C$ of $\mathbb R$ in two dimensional space.